# How can I get $\int_{R_\rho}|x|^{\gamma r}|u|^r$ from $\int_{R_1}|u|^r $.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, estimation

Let $u\in \mathcal C^1_c(\mathbb R^n)$. I have that $$\int_{R_1}|u|^r\leq C\left(\int_{R_1}|\nabla u|^p\right)^{ar/p}\left(\int_{R_1}|u|^q\right)^{(1-a)r/q},$$
where $R_\rho=\{x\in \mathbb R^n\mid \rho\leq |x|<2\rho\}.$

Then it's written in my course that : Rescaling and multiplying by $\rho^{\gamma r}$ we get 
$$\int_{R_\rho}|x|^{\gamma r}|u|^r\leq C\left(\int_{R_\rho}|x|^{\alpha r}|\nabla u|^p\right)^{ar/p}\left(\int_{R_\rho}|x|^{\beta q}|u|^q\right)^{(1-a)r/q},$$
where $$\frac{1}{r}+\frac{\gamma }{n}=a\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{\alpha -1}{n}\right)+(1-a)\left(\frac{1}{q}+\frac{\beta }{n}\right),$$
$\gamma =a\varphi+(1-a)\beta $.

**Question**

Could someone explain me how to get this ? I tried a substitution as $y=\rho^{\gamma r}x$, but no $|x|$ appear.

Comment: *YOUR MISTAKE**: Don't Forget that $x\in R_1=\{x\in \mathbb R^n\mid 1\leq |x|<2 \} $ is set So putting $$y=\rho^{\gamma r}R_1$$
Does not make any sense as change of variables but rather you should put
$$y=\rho^{\gamma r}x~~~\text{with}~~x\in R_1$$ 

$$R_\rho=\{x\in \mathbb R^n\mid \rho\leq |x|<2\rho\}.$$

Comment: @GuyFsone: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, after the substitution the $|x|^\gamma $ doesn't appear, no ? Because $dy=\rho^{\gamma r}dx.$

Comment: becarefull your jacobian should be raise to power n. check again

Comment: @GuyFsone: Yes indeed, thank :-) But I still no have $|x|$ that appear.

Comment: you finally completly changed your post now the problem absolutely clear

Comment: @GuyFsone: You are unfair ! I din't change anything (I just erase the last sentence). The question is the same since the first day. You can see in the edit to be sure ;-) You just had a bad interpretation of the question at the beginning, that's all ! But anyways, thank you for your consideration since the beginning, I appreciated that you tried to help me :-)

Comment: I am unfair you are right where is this factor then, it does not appears anymore in your post. $$ \int_{R_{\rho^{r\gamma }}}\frac{1}{\rho^{r\gamma }}|u(y)|^q dy$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626893/how-interpret-x-gamma-u-lr-leq-c-nabla-u-lpa-x-beta-u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u : R_\rho \to \mathbb{R}$ and then rescale by defining $v : R_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ via $v(x) = u(\rho x)$.  We apply your inequality to $v$ to get
$$
\int_{R_1}|v|^r\leq C\left(\int_{R_1}|\nabla v|^p\right)^{ar/p}\left(\int_{R_1}|v|^q\right)^{(1-a)r/q}.
$$
Now we change variables:
$$
\int_{R_1} |v(x)|^r dx = \int_{R_1} |u(\rho x)|^r dx = \rho^{-n} \int_{R_\rho} |u(y)|^r dy,
$$
$$
\int_{R_1} |v(x)|^q dx = \int_{R_1} |u(\rho x)|^q dx = \rho^{-n} \int_{R_\rho} |u(y)|^q dy,
$$
and
$$
\int_{R_1} |\nabla v(x)|^p dx = \int_{R_1} \rho^p |\nabla u(\rho x)|^p dx = \rho^{p-n} \int_{R_\rho} |\nabla u(y)|^p dy.
$$

Now, for $y \in R_\rho$ we have that $\rho \le |y| \le 2 \rho$, and so $\rho^\delta \le |y|^\delta \le 2^\delta \rho^\delta$ for any $\delta >0$.  Thus
$$
\rho^{-n} \int_{R_\rho} |u(y)|^r dy \ge \frac{\rho^{-\gamma r-n}}{2^{\gamma r}} \int_{R_\rho} |y|^{\gamma r}|u(y)|^r dy,
$$
$$
\rho^{-n} \int_{R_\rho} |u(y)|^q dy \le \rho^{-\beta q-n} \int_{R_\rho} |y|^{\beta q} |u(y)|^q dy,
$$
and
$$
\rho^{p-n} \int_{R_\rho} |\nabla u(y)|^p dy \le \rho^{p-n-\alpha p} \int_{R_\rho} |y|^{\alpha p}|\nabla u(y)|^p dy.
$$

Combining all these shows that 
$$
 \frac{\rho^{-\gamma r-n}}{2^{\gamma r}} \int_{R_\rho} |y|^{\gamma r}|u(y)|^r dy \le  C \left( \rho^{p-n-\alpha p} \int_{R_\rho} |y|^{\alpha p}|\nabla u(y)|^p dy \right)^{ar/p} \left( \rho^{-\beta q-n} \int_{R_\rho} |y|^{\beta q} |u(y)|^q dy \right)^{(1-a)r/q}. 
$$

Now, if $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,p,q,r,a$ are chosen so that 
$$
(1-a)\left( \frac{\beta}{n} + \frac{1}{q} \right) +a\left(\frac{1}{p} + \frac{\alpha-1}{n} \right) = \frac{\gamma}{n} + \frac{1}{r}
$$
then the $\rho$ terms exactly cancel out and we're left with
$$
 \int_{R_\rho} |y|^{\gamma r}|u(y)|^r dy \le  2^{\gamma r} C \left(  \int_{R_\rho} |y|^{\alpha p}|\nabla u(y)|^p dy \right)^{ar/p} \left(   \int_{R_\rho} |y|^{\beta q} |u(y)|^q dy \right)^{(1-a)r/q}. 
$$
I realize this isn't exactly what you've asked for, but I suspect there are two typos in your post.  First, I suspect you want the power to be $\alpha p$ in the gradient integral, and second I suspect there's a sign error on the $\alpha-1$ term.  At least, this is what I get when I adjust the power in the gradient term.

Comment: In fact it answer totally to my answer. Thank you very much :-)